# java fxml open new window on click listview

Tags: java, listview, java-8, fxml

I have a `ListView` with some messages. I want to open a new window when I click on a message in the `ListView`. For some reason the `.fxml` file fails to load and I can't seem to find out why. I suspect I'm overlooking something.

```
@FXML
private void handleSentMsg(MouseEvent event){
    String content = sentLvw.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getContent();
    Profile receiver = sentLvw.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getReceiver();
    Profile sender = sentLvw.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getSender();
    GregorianCalendar gc = sentLvw.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getTimestamp();
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader4 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ReceivedMsg.fxml"));
        Parent root4 = (Parent) fxmlLoader4.load();
        Stage stage4 = new Stage();
        // Lock ApplicationController, NewMsg needs to be closed first.
        stage4.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage4.setTitle("Ontvangen bericht van ");
        stage4.setScene(new Scene(root4));
        // Data meegeven aan de nieuwe controller.
        ReceivedMsgController controller4 = fxmlLoader4.<ReceivedMsgController>getController();
        controller4.setGc(gc);
        controller4.setContent(content);
        controller4.setSender(sender);
        controller4.setReceiver(receiver);
        stage4.show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Can't load new window!");
    }
}
```

The debugger exits at this line:

```
Parent root4 = (Parent) fxmlLoader4.load();
```

The ReceivedMsg.fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="428.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.datingsite.gui.ReceivedMsgController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="247.0" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="94.0" text="KiHU">
         <font>
            <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="242.0" layoutY="81.0" text="Ontvangen bericht" />
      <Label layoutX="73.0" layoutY="130.0" text="Van:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="51.0" />
      <Label fx:id="sentLbl" layoutX="137.0" layoutY="162.0" text="Timestamp" />
      <Label layoutX="72.0" layoutY="162.0" text="Verstuurd:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="51.0" />
      <Label fx:id="senderLbl" layoutX="137.0" layoutY="130.0" text="VerzenderLabel" />
      <Label layoutX="50.0" layoutY="200.0" text="Bericht:" />
      <TextArea fx:id="messageTxt" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="223.0" prefHeight="140.0" prefWidth="529.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="51.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="51.0" />
      <Button layoutX="434.0" layoutY="381.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#backButton" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="101.0" text="Terug" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="51.0" />
      <Button layoutX="252.0" layoutY="381.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#checkProfileButton" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="101.0" text="Bekijk profiel" />
      <Button layoutX="51.0" layoutY="381.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sendMessageButton" text="Verstuur bericht" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="51.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The complete stack trace, but is does not show much as a try catch is being executed:

```
Listening on javadebug
User program running
Not able to submit breakpoint MethodBreakpoint [org.datingsite.domain.ParticipantInfo].checkParticipantInfo '(Lorg/datingsite/domain/ParticipantInfo;)Z', reason: Method 'checkParticipantInfo' with signature '(Lorg/datingsite/domain/ParticipantInfo;)Z' does not exist in class org.datingsite.domain.ParticipantInfo.
LineBreakpoint ApplicationController.java : 323 successfully submitted.
MethodBreakpoint [org.datingsite.gui.ApplicationController].sitesButton '(Ljavafx/event/ActionEvent;)V' successfully submitted.
Breakpoint hit at line 323 in class org.datingsite.gui.ApplicationController by thread JavaFX Application Thread.
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped at ApplicationController.java:323.
User program running
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to 'getSelectionModel()' at ApplicationController.java:323.
User program running
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to 'getSelectedItem()' at ApplicationController.java:323.
User program running
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to 'getTimestamp()' at ApplicationController.java:323.
User program running
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to 'getClass()' at ApplicationController.java:325.
User program running
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to 'getResource()' at ApplicationController.java:325.
User program running
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to '<init>()' at ApplicationController.java:325.
User program running
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to 'load()' at ApplicationController.java:326.
User program running
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to 'println()' at ApplicationController.java:340.
User program finished
```

Stack trace part2:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Marcel\\code\\KTV-2016 -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Marcel\code\KTV-2016\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Marcel\code\KTV-2016\build\built-jar.properties
wsimport-init:
wsimport-client-DatingSite:
files are up to date
wsimport-client-generate:
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Marcel\code\KTV-2016\build\classes
Note: C:\Users\Marcel\code\KTV-2016\src\org\datingsite\gui\ApplicationController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
compile:
run:
You clicked me!
Can't load new window!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)
```

Thanks for the time already invested in this, let me know if I need to come up with more info. I would really like to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: could you possibly attach a stack trace?

Comment: Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to 'load()' at ApplicationController.java:326.
User program running
Thread JavaFX Application Thread stopped before call to 'println()' at ApplicationController.java:340.
User program finished

Comment: Could you give the contents of the `ReceivedMsg.fxml` file. Also, please edit the question to give the `complete stack trace`

Comment: please post the complete exception instead of swallowing it. Replace this line `System.out.println("Can't load new window!");` with this `e.printStackTrace();` . Probably there is an issue with your controller

Comment: It was obviously way too late last night, thank you for the tip @AntJavaDev, the problem was in the initialize method in the ReceivedMsgController class. it doesn't let me set the labels in the new window directly. I learned a valuable lesson though, always first enable e.printStackTrace();

Comment: :) yep , bad practice to code when you are really tired. Also just a tip in case that your application is going to be distributed , generally `e.printStackTrace();` should be used only for debug / development reasons. Consider using a logging framework which you later may customize it as , i suppose that , your application is going to run without a command prompt window